# Circular dependencies Angular (Just the file name)

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

Previously, I had separate files for interfaces and services, but I merged them into the same file as I was always requesting them together. i.e. user.interface.ts + user.service.ts => user.service.ts - where the user interface and service are declared. It's made developing a lot quicker, not having to open/ require so many files.

One issue I'm having is that I get a circular dependency warning when just importing the interface from the file (which creates a file loop). I'm assuming there are no issues with this and it's just a dumb warning? If so, is there a way to filter out these warnings without filtering out circular services?

**File example**

Service A

```
import { ServiceB } from '../serviceB.service';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {}
```

Service B

```
import { C1, C2 } from '../serviceC.service';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceB {}
```

Service C

```
import { ServiceD } from '../serviceD.service';

export interface C1 {}

export interface C2 {}

@Injectable()
export class ServiceC {}
```

Service D

```
import { ServiceA } from '../serviceA.service';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceD {
```

Comment: Share the file.

Comment: There is indeed a circular dependency in your imports. D imports A which imports B which imports C which imports D then importing A again and so on. In other words, your ServiceD importing ServiceA is creating a circular dependency.

Comment: `A -> B -> C -> D -> A` a perfect circle!

You should rethink your architecture to bust up this circular dependency. If `A` is implicity importing `D` via `B` and `C`. Then `A` has everything. No need to make `D` depend on `A`. 

It's a perfect one-way street. Don't turn back.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly, `ServiceB` depends on `serviceC.service` only for its interfaces `C1` and `C2`.

Why don't you move `C1` and `C2` to a separate file?

That way

```
C -> D -> A -> B -> interfaces
```

...and your circle is broken.

Comment: I know I can move the interfaces to a different file and it will break the circle, I'd just prefer not to, to keep the structure consistent. The app builds fine, and I don't think it does if there is a service circle. So what I'm really wondering, is if there's an actual issue with this or it's just being caught by a simple algorithm Angular uses to identify possible circle dependencies.

Comment: @d9nny IMHO it is better better to not mix interfaces with implementations. Maybe looking at the actual code would however make your choice more understandable.